# Launching persistent scripts from overarching script?

Tags: python

I have a Python 2.7.X script that acts as a simple web server (which is one aspect of a larger project).  I'm building a "driver" script that controls the larger project, but one of the functions of the "driver" script includes launching the web server if it isn't already running.

When I run the web server on it's one, it has a `serve_forever()` method running so if I called that module from my "driver" script, I would never get to anything below that call.

Is there a way to launch the web server script from my "driver" script as a separate thread/process (not sure of the proper verbiage) so I can continue to execute other things in my "driver" script?

Edit for clarification:
The "driver" script may be called multiple times to perform different actions.  This means that the first time the "driver" script is called, it may spin up the web server.  After launching the web server, the "driver" script finishes.  While the web server is running, the "driver" script can be launched again to perform a separate action.  Therefore, when launching the web server, the web server must continue to run until the "driver" script is run with a "terminate server" option.

Comment: Use `thread.py` and make sure to make the new thread a daemon

Comment: Do you mean the `threading.py` module?  While looking in the docs of `thread.py`, I couldn't find anything referencing "daemon".

Comment: Yes, sorry I mixed up Py27 and Py36